# awk printf with variable

Tags: bash, awk

The following expression works as expected:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 4/3}'
1.33333
```

However if I use a variable in place of the literal value then it does not print
as expected:

```
$ awk -v foo=4/3 'BEGIN {print foo}'
4/3
```

How can use use a variable with an `awk` `printf` expression?

This is a workaround:

```
$ printf 'BEGIN {print %s}' 4/3 | awk -f-
1.33333
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `foo=4/3` sets `foo` to the string `4/3`.  When that is printed via `%f`, '4/3' is treated as `4`; when that is printed with `%s`, it is printed as `4/3`.  If you want to evaluate the expression, you need it evaluated inside the script.

For example:

```
awk 'END {printf "%f\n", foonum/fooden }' foonum=4 fooden=3 /dev/null
```

Note that `bash` does not do floating point arithmetic.  Thus this produces 1 as the output:

```
awk 'END {printf "%s\n", foo }' foo=$((4/3)) /dev/null
```

Maybe you want to use `bc`:

```
$ bc -l <<< "4/3"
1.33333333333333333333
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax issue, following works:

```
awk 'END {foo=4/3; printf "%f", foo}' /dev/null
```

OR to pass the value from shell to awk:

```
foo=$(bc -l <<< 4/3) && awk -v foo=$foo 'END {printf "%f\n", foo}' /dev/null
```

Please note that **awk doesn't have any eval() function** So if you want to evaluate a maths expression inside awk by passing whole expression in a String like your example then use something like this:

```
awk 'END {"bc -l <<< " foo|getline foo; printf("%f\n", foo)}' foo='4/3' /dev/null
```

**Edit without use of bc:**

```
awk 'END {split(foo, a, "/"); printf("%f\n", a[1]/a[2])}' foo='4/3' /dev/null
```